# Video Filter module warning

Tags: 8, input-formats

I have installed the video filter module on my site. I added the following to my video source field.

```
[video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=686A5yPMWrs]
```

When I view the node, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in Drupal\video_filter\Plugin\Filter\VideoFilter->process() (line 91 of modules/video_filter/src/Plugin/Filter/VideoFilter.php).

Is this something to pursue and fix? Is it safe to just disable the warnings when I push the site live?

Answer (score 1):

The [Video Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_filter) is still in alpha so it's very likely this is a bug. You should consult the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/video_filter?categories=All) to see if it exists, and create a bug report if it doesn't exist.

As for the ignore and deploy/pursue and fix question, it depends on how fault tolerant you are. Certainly the project maintainers (and community) would appreciate the bug fix. Deploying early release code is risky, but if the functionality is little used and has no chance of catastrophic results (e.g. complex DB manipulation that could result in corruption.) then deploy/ignore can be a fine strategy (regardless, you should always have warnings turned off on production).